# Reading .env with bash (vars with spaces)

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

I'm using nodedock.

It has a start.sh script to start you docker

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"

if [ ! -f .env ]; then
  echo "Having .env is required. Maybe you forgot to copy env-example?"
  exit 1
fi

while read -r line; do
  VARNAME=$(echo ${line} | awk '{sub(/\=.*/,x)}1')

  if [[ -z ${!VARNAME} ]]; then
    declare -x ${line}
  fi
done < <(egrep -v "(^#|^\s|^$)" .env)

docker-compose up -d ${NODEDOCK_SERVICES}
docker-compose logs -t -f ${NODEDOCK_LOG_AFTER_START}
```

`NODEDOCK_SERVICES = nginx node workspace mongo`

If found that if you need to have a variable with spaces you have to write your env variable with doubles quotes `"nginx node workspace mongo"`

The problem is that this "req expression" `VARNAME=$(echo ${line} | awk '{sub(/\=.*/,x)}1')` doesn't work with double quotes.

Any solution?

Comment: Does your line in the file contain the assignment `NODEDOCK_SERVICES = nginx node workspace mongo` with or without spaces around `=`?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ found the declare quoting issue as well as other issues.

Comment: I didn't have the time to try your solution. As soon as I try it, I will check as correct. Don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* with your `awk` expression but when you make a call to the `declare` built-in. Use proper quotes when declaring it.

```
declare -x "$str"
```

because without the quotes, your assignment would look like

```
declare -x NODEDOCK_SERVICES=nginx node workspace mongo
```

which splits on white-space and the first word of the resultant string gets assigned to `NODEDOCK_SERVICES`. But with proper quotes, the assignment would remain intact preserving the spaces in the resultant string.

That said, your whole loop can be modified by making the `read` loop parse the line with `=` as de-limiter, so you can easily parse the key/value pairs. At this point it is *not* clear that the assignments in your file would be of the form 1 or 2 below

```
NODEDOCK_SERVICES = nginx node workspace mongo
NODEDOCK_SERVICES=nginx node workspace mongo
```

The below logic would work for both the cases

```sh
shopt -s extglob
while IFS== read -r key value; do 
    key=${key%%+([[:space:]])}  
    value=${value##+([[:space:]])} 
    if [[ -z ${!key} ]]; then
        declare -x "$key=$value"
    fi
done < <(egrep -v "(^#|^\s|^$)" .env)
```

As a good practice, always quote your variables in `bash`, unless you see a good reason not to. And lower-casing user defined variables helps you distinguish them from the environment variables maintained by the shell itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read specific variables from an .env file format (maybe not exactly your question but it might help others as your title might be misleading):

```
read_var() {
    VAR=$(grep "^$1=" $2 | xargs)
    IFS="=" read -ra VAR <<< "$VAR"
    IFS=" "
    echo ${VAR[1]}
}
```